# Button inside of MapView is not displayed

Tags: android

I'd like to place `Button` on the `MapView` at top|end.
 
But `Button` i added doesn't show up.
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqPMM.jpg)

I made `MapFragment` to show on main activity's `FrameLayout`

**main** xml

```
...
-------- Here is Layout i want to show Map --------
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize">
</FrameLayout>
------------------------------------------------------
...
```

This is **MapFragment** xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainFragment">

<net.daum.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anything i should describe more please comment.

---

**+Edited** 
Changed `MapFragment` xml

```
<net.daum.android.map.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
    </net.daum.android.map.MapView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and added method in `MapFragment.java`

```
btn.bringToFront();
```

now it works. [Works Fine img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zspse.png)

Thanks for help!

Comment: I think u changed from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. Relativelayout has different attributes. try alignParentEnd="true" and alignParentTop="true" and remove layout_gravity

Comment: If still not showing, try btn.bringToFront() programmatically.

Comment: @HeinHtetAung It works now. I couldn’t have done it without you. I really want to thank you for your help. Stay healthy!!!!

Comment: glad i could help u. :D

Answer (score 0):

You want to add the button on top of the map view in the top right corner correct?

currently you have the map view set to

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

so naturally the map view is taking up the whole relative layout.

```
<net.daum.android.map.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent" />

</net.daum.android.map.MapView>
```

try this

Comment: + it was also helpful to me. Thank you!!